# pandas remove groups that each element have the same value on a column in every group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need to do a `groupby` for a `df`, and then within each group, I want to check if every element in that group has the same value on a column `A`, if so, remove the group,

```
 df['cluster_id'] = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D'])['B'].transform('size')

 df = df.loc[
        df['cluster_id'] > 1 &
        df['cluster_id'] == df['cluster_id'] &
        df['A'] != df['A']]
```

but I got error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I am wondering how to fix it.

Comment: @cmaher thx the error is gone

Comment: Do you still have the problem or have you solved it?

Comment: @daiyue Whats the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `()` are missing:

```
df =df[(df['cluster_id'] > 1) & (df['cluster_id'] == df['cluster_id']) & (df['A'] != df['A'])]
```

Also it seems second condition is not necessary:

```
df = df[(df['cluster_id'] > 1) & (df['A'] != df['A'])]
```

Also new column is not necessary, is possible compare by `Series`:

```
cluster_id = df.groupby(['B', 'C', 'D'])['B'].transform('size')

df = df[(cluster_id > 1) & (cluster_id == cluster_id) & (df['A'] != df['A'])]
```

---

```
df = df[(cluster_id > 1) & (df['A'] != df['A'])]
```

Comment: wondering why the second condition is not necessary, the condition specifies the elements should be in the same group.

Comment: @daiyue - Myabe I am wrong, but `(df['cluster_id'] == df['cluster_id'])` should be always `True`s. (if not `NaNs`)

Comment: how to properly specify a condition indicating that rows in the same cluster in this case?

Comment: @daiyue - I create sample `df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A':[4,5,4,5,5,4,1,4,7],
                   'C':[1] * 9,
                   'D':[2] * 9,
                   'B':list('aaabbccde')})`

Comment: @daiyue -so what should be `df['cluster_id'] == df['cluster_id']` ? hmmm, do you think compare like `df['cluster_id'] != df['A']` ? Because `(df['A'] != df['A'])` always return `False`

Comment: created another post tried to resolve this problem but got into some problem using numpy.unique and filter, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293962/numpy-unique-could-not-filter-out-groups-with-the-same-value-on-a-specific-colum