# numpy unique could not filter out groups with the same value on a specific column

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I tried to `groupby` a `df` and then select groups who do not have the same value on a specific column and whose group size > 1,

```
df.groupby(['account_no', 'ext_id', 'amount']).filter(lambda x: (len(x) > 1) & (np.unique(x.int_id).size != 1))
```

the `df` looks like, note that some `account_no` strings only have a single space, `ext_id` and `int_id` are also strings, `amount` is `float`;

```
account_no    ext_id    amount        int_id
              2665057   439.504062     D000192
              2665057   439.504062     D000192
              353724    2758.92        952
              353724    2758.92        952
```

the code supposed to return an empty `df`, since none of the rows in the sample satisfy the conditions here, but the rows with `int_id = 292` remained, so how to fix the issue here.

ps. `numpy 1.14.3`, `pandas 0.22.0`, `python 3.5.2`

Comment: The `amount` column contains floating point values.  Are you sure those two values that display as `438.01` are *exactly* the same?  Perhaps one is `438.01` and the other is, for example, `438.01000000000005`.  Verify that `df.amount[0] == df.amount[1]`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser `amount[0] == amount[1]` is `true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is problem some traling whitespace or similar.

You can check it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'account_no': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'], 
                   'ext_id': [2665057, 2665057, 353724, 353724], 
                   'amount': [439.50406200000003, 439.50406200000003, 2758.92, 2758.92], 
                   'int_id': ['D000192', 'D000192', ' 952', '952']})
print (df)
  account_no       amount   ext_id   int_id
0          a   439.504062  2665057  D000192
1          a   439.504062  2665057  D000192
2          a  2758.920000   353724      952
3          a  2758.920000   353724      952

df1 = df.groupby(['account_no', 'ext_id', 'amount']).filter(lambda x: (len(x) > 1) & (np.unique(x.int_id).size != 1))
print (df1)
  account_no   amount  ext_id int_id
2          a  2758.92  353724    952
3          a  2758.92  353724    952

print (df1['int_id'].tolist())
[' 952', '952']
```

And then remove it by `str.strip`:

```
df['int_id'] = df['int_id'].str.strip()
df1 = df.groupby(['account_no', 'ext_id', 'amount']).filter(lambda x: (len(x) > 1) & (np.unique(x.int_id).size != 1))
print (df1)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [account_no, amount, ext_id, int_id]
Index: []
```

Comment: there are no spaces around `int_id`, if I did `df.loc[idx_1]['int_id'] == df.loc[idx_2]['int_id']` is `True`, where `idx_1/2` are the indices that lead to the rows that have the same `int_id` in the same group, so I am thinking `pandas.nunique/unique` or `np.unique` is bugged, since `group = df.groupby(['account_no', 'ext_id', 'amount'])['int_id'].nunique()` then `group[group.apply(lambda x:x==1)]` gave me empty series - `Series([], Name: int_id, dtype: int64)`

Comment: Maybe yes, I also think if no exist same groups in another rows? What return this alternative `df = df[df.groupby(['account_no', 'ext_id', 'amount'])['int_id'].transform('nunique') > 1]` ?

Comment: it returns the `df` still having rows with the same `int_id` values as discussed above.

Comment: @daiyue - are data confidental?

Comment: because it seems some data problem.

Comment: yes, you are right, i found the row that caused the problem through a grid search, luckly the data set is not too big.